# Print PDF File Directly through Printer IP Address in Java Programming

Tags: sockets, pdf, printing

I got a task, to print a PDF file through an IP of Printer.
I can do it with javax.print.PrintService, but the Printer need to be installed in PC / Laptop. I've been trying, to convert PDF to PS File. Still not Working,

Comment: So it can not be done?

Comment: I want to Print Like Shipment Papper, on A4 Paper using like Epson M1120.